# Desktop icons not appearing in GNOME 3.24 even after enabling them in GNOME Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.04

I've put files and folders into my Desktop directory but they're not appearing on the Desktop even though the setting to show desktop icons is enabled in GNOME Tweak Tool and even though I enabled the setting in the dconf editor as well. I also can't drag icons onto the desktop either.

Comment: Did you log out/in to reload GNOME Shell?

Comment: Yes, I've logged in/out, restarted, and have reloaded the GNOME Shell with Alt+F2 and the 'r' command.